X2Go Client Crashes on Ubuntu 24.04 Raspberry Pi 5: Segmentation Fault Issue
I need to connect to an X2Go server from my Raspberry Pi 5 running Ubuntu 24.04. I've installed the x2goclient 4.1.2.4 package using apt. However, every time I connect to the server, the application crashes before the remote desktop is rendered. The console output is "segmentation fault".
I have also tried Remmina with the X2Go plugin (sudo apt install -y remmina-plugin-x2go) but without success. Remmina also crashes when connecting. The connection works when I connect with X2Go for windows from another PC, so the server is fine.
Any ideas on how to get an X2Go client connection on Ubuntu 24.04 for RPi5?

Check and make sure you're not using wayland, just had this issue this morning.
I installed the remmina-plugin-x2go and when I tried to make a connection using remmina it said something wasn't supported on wayland, log into X session and the original client works fine.

Sounds promising. I am quite sure I am using wayland. How would I log into X session? Or is it somehow possible to just have remmina use X11 for rendering its interface while the system is running in wayland?

Apoligies for the late response, logout of your desktop environment and when you select your user to log back in, before you enter your password there should be a settings wheel where you can select X11 or wayland.

That worked, thank you so much :)
